# best resource video for learning php

Tags: php, video

I recently found this post on SO:
[best-resources-to-learn-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript)

and have really learned a lot from Douglas Crockford's video series.

I'm not new to PHP, but I **would like to see a comparable video series on PHP (either from a beginner's perspective, or from a more advance angle)**

- Can anyone suggest similar videos / lecture series on PHP that are as well thought out and presented?
- In a related vein, I would also appreciate links to really awesome videos that introduce the DOM (I did see Crockford's DOM videos, but would like to see more)

Answer (score 2):

Video:
 - [KillerPHP](http://killerphp.com/)

Sites:
 - [W3Schools Tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/DEfaULT.asP)

Books:
 - [PHP Anthology Vol 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0957921853)
 - [PHP Anthology Vol 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0957921845)

Forums:
 - [WebDeveloper.com](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=16)

Comment: It's funny to see that the link "Start learning PHP now!" from site "W3Schools Tutorials" points to an asp page.

Answer (score 0):

videos are fine, but for a beginner, i think [this book](http://www.amazon.ca/Wicked-Cool-PHP-Real-World-Difficult/dp/1593271735) is invaluable kryptonite

Comment: I have the Object Oriented PHP book by the same publisher and several books in the friends of ed series.  I like them all, but was hoping for something along the lines of the Crockford 'the best parts' advice lectures -- but for php.

Answer (score 0):

I Think one of the best book would be ::

```
    Wicked Cool PHP 
        by William Steinmetz, Brian Ward
```