# Ask SO: Good PHP code to read?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

It's quite easy for me to study html/css, as it's openly available.

But I can't do the same with PHP/AJAX (and MySQL). I'm trying to learn both, but there's not much good code to find.

Any tips where I can find some (to read and to use)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [best resource video for learning php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848146/best-resource-video-for-learning-php) and [plenty others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=learn+code+php)

Answer (score 2):

Read code to learn? I generally start writing code to learn it after the end of the tutorial. Go to http://www.w3schools.com/ that contain tutorial, sample code and a practice tool for you to write code and test it online.

Answer (score 1):

Try all the tutorials you can find. After you feel like you cannot learn anything from them try and build an application.

You could also get a look at some php frameworks

Answer (score 0):

Read [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org), [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com) and [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org). Those are very well written.

Comment: He's a beginner... I don't think it's useful to look at the underlying code of these frameworks. He'd better start by looking at code for a simple blog or something.

Comment: @captain Cake and CI might be somewhat complex, but Wordpress is reasonably simple.

Comment: @captain @deceze Maybe a CRUD only framework would be interesting, something minimal...

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do in my eyes (its how I learned a huge amount intially) is to have a specific task you want to achieve, then break that task into logical steps and try to find information/tutorials to tackle each one. Then use google to pinpoint targetted tutorials (seriously, google is a heck of a resource, dont put it down, its basically an online library).

So, say you wanted a way of uploading a file into a database using HTML, PHP and mySQL - that is your task. The next thing would just be to search for say, '[PHP mySQL file upload tutorial how to](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&expIds=17259,17315,23628,26637,26761,26849,26869,27404,27510,27520,27547,27584&xhr=t&q=PHP+mySQL+file+upload+tutorial+how+to&cp=37&pf=p&sclient=psy&site=&source=hp&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=PHP+mySQL+file+upload+tutorial+how+to&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=e1e5bf14d885c19c)'.

Frameworks are great tools for developing your applications, however I would tend to say (personal opinion) that at least initially, it is better to learn straight PHP, the ins and outs, the basic functions and uses. This will help give you the knowledge of how to apply/develop with a framework better as you will understand the advantages it offers relative to straight PHP and therefore how to utilise the framework more efficiently.